# AC Power measurement ( digital sampling)

Tags: power, ac, current-measurement, voltage-measurement

i want to measure AC power and i want to know what is the best and safest way to digital sample AC voltage and AC current?

For AC voltage: We can use

- voltage divider and feed it to ADC with reference eg -5V to 5V ( non isolated)
- transformer to transformer from 230VAC to 5VAC and feed it  to ADC (isolated)
- use voltage divider and isolation opamp or ADC ( isolated)
- are there any other options?

For AC current: We can use

- shunt resistor with opamp to adc ( non isolated and high dissipation on shunt)
- shunt resistor with isolation opamp or ADC ( same as above with isolation)
- current transformer ( can you suggest some ?) ( isolated)
- hall effect sensor ( can you suggest some?) ( isolated)
- are there any other options?

Because i need to sample the voltage and current at the same time i need two ADC, but i'm not sure what delay will be introduced for voltage ( if use any option from above) also for current  ( if use any option from above) ? And if delay is introduced how can i synchronize the two ADC?

List of priorities:

1. size
2. price
3. low power ( as possible)
4. complexity

The voltage is 230Vac and max current 16A and if possible current resolution 100mA

Br.

Comment: Have a look at https://openenergymonitor.org/ where all of this has been sorted out already. Voltage and current transformers will be the safest option. Shopping questions are off-topic, I'm afraid.

Comment: Hi Andy, i was asking about advice to learn something new, and not that someone only tells this is above your credentials, this is not nice. Under ADC synchronization i meant do i need to search the AC voltage zero crossing and trigger booth ADC with this signal, or is there a better way? ( I know how to setup ADC in uC our separate ADC with any kind of interface to uC.

My concern is if i do isolated with Opamp then i will introduce a delay, but if i use isolation transformer for voltage and current transformer for current will i also then introduce delay ?

Comment: With only resistor divider on voltage and shunt on current i will not introduce delay but then this is not isolated approach and the shunt for current will dissipate a lot of power. But again there are also isolated ADC eg AMC1336.

Comment: Also for current sense will the hall sensor introduce a delay, are there any recommendation for AC current hall sensor?